# How to show hyperlink for particular text in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hyperlink

Here is my code

```
<a href="#" ><font style="color:#000000;">
    PLEASE CLICK HERE FOR MORE DETAILS</font> </a>
```

Here, Hyperlink is given to whole word `PLEASE CLICK HERE FOR MORE DETAILS`

I need to give hyperlink on mouse hover to the text `HERE`
Is it possible using html itself or I need to go with JavaScript/Jquery?

Comment: What do you mean by "give hyperlink"?

Comment: Try this:<font style="color:#000000;">
    PLEASE CLICK <a href="#" >HERE</a> FOR MORE DETAILS</font>

Comment: Please stop using `<font>` tags, they're long-deprecated.

Comment: Instead of blaming the code, try to give answer @DavidThomas

Comment: You have your answer(s); and I'm not 'blaming the code,' or you (though *you* wrote that code); I am, however, pointing out that the `<font>` is deprecated. This was intended to be helpful advice, you're not required to follow my suggestion however.

Comment: inside link you want to give a link, huh!!!!

Comment: Thank you all :) Hi C-link..Welcome..you are one of my favorite user..I got the answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
<font style="color:#000000;">PLEASE CLICK <a href="#" >HERE</a> FOR MORE DETAILS</font>
```

Add styles

```
a {
  text-decoration:none; 
}
a:hover{
  text-decoration:underline;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can change your HTML to:

```
<span style="color:#000000;">PLEASE CLICK <a href="#" >HERE</a> FOR MORE DETAILS</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

**css**

```
   span{
    color:#000;
    }

    span a{
    color:blue;
    }
```

**HTML**

```
<span>PLEASE <a href="#">CLICK</a> HERE FOR MORE DETAILS</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this

**HTML:**

```
<span><font style="color:#000000;">
    PLEASE CLICK HERE FOR MORE DETAILS</font></span>
```

**JQUERY:**

```
$("span").mouseover(function() {
$(this).html("PLEASE CLICK <a href='#'>HERE</a> FOR MORE DETAILS");
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/CYLcY/42/)

Comment: why to use jQuery if simple HTML can do this?

Comment: he need hyperlink on mouse-over that's why i use it...may be you could do this by different way

Comment: op does not want hyperlink to whole sentence. He just want "here" text to hyperlink. See below answers which is in HTML

Comment: i think you dont see fiddle output......this code just give hyperlink  to "here" text........

Comment: dude im not saying your answer is wrong but this can be achievable through HTML too so there is no need to use jQuery anyways op have accept the answer

Comment: wht i understand that op needs hyperlink on mouse hover .....so for achieving it i use jquery.

Comment: see accepted answer for this question. You have not read question properly.

Answer (score 1):

from what I understand of what you're saying I think you need a link that just looks like a link when the mouse hovers on it.

There are many ways to do this but by far the simpler is using simple CSS and HTML.

Try using:

HTML:

```
    <p> hello this is a <a href="#" class="hoverL">link</a>, 
        but it doesn't look like one unless you hover your mouse on it</p>
```

CSS:

```
 .hoverL{
            text-decoration: none; /* Eliminates the decoration (the underline)*/
            color: inherit; /* inherits the text color from it's parent */
    }

.hoverL:hover{
            text-decoration: underline; /* underline it again */
            color: blue; /* and give it again it's original color */
    }
```

Here you can see a working jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/G6Lb6/

hope this is what you needed :)

Comment: If you want then instead of using a class (in this case "hoverL") you can also use the simple html selector "a" to give this styles to every link

Answer (score -1):

Please don't use `<font style="color:#000000;">` it's deprecated and was declined by HTML 4.01

You can just link "Here" inside a span:

```
<span>Please click <a href="#">here</a> for more details </span>

a:hover {
 color:#000;
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/font - I don't understand why it is downvoted...